# More than one Excel If statement for analysing and receiving a time range

Tags: excel, if-statement, timeval

I'm trying to have two cells, so I when I enter midnight (or 0:00) in the first cell I get 8am ( or 8:00) in the second cell. But if I put 8am in the first cell I get 4pm in the second cell. As well as if I put 4pm in the first cell I get midnight in the second cell.

This is the if statement I came up with::

```
=IF(AND(C6=TIMEVALUE("08:00:00")),TIMEVALUE("16:00:00"),IF(AND(C6=TIMEVALUE("08:00:00")),TIMEVALUE("16:00:00"),0.327,IF(C6=TIMEVALUE("08:00:00")),TIMEVALUE("16:00:00")))
```

I tried the first IF without the AND (only) getting it to work but that is it

Comment: I think you might need to describe what you are trying to accomplish. While the included original effort is appreciated, it makes no sense to me at least.

Comment: Could you please explain more in detail please?

Comment: your ANDs don't have any additional tests. I also think there is a syntax error. Potentially, I could be wrong, what you have written equates to IF(C6=TIMEVALUE("08:00:00"),TIMEVALUE("16:00:00"),0.327)

Comment: I edited my question, I hope I made it clear to what I am trying to ask